# How to print JSON on golang template?

Tags: go, go-templates

I need a object in client side, so I converted it to JSON using json.marshal and printed it into template. The object is getting printed as escaped JSON string.

I'm expecting it to be `var arr=["o1","o2"]` but it is `var arr="[\"o1\",\"o2\"]"`

I know I can JSON.parse in client side, but is that the only way?

Here is how I'm printing it in template:

`{{ marshal .Arr }}`

Here is my marshal function:

```
"marshal": func(v interface {}) string {
  a, _ := json.Marshal(v)
  return string(a)
},
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In JS context normal strings always gets escaped. I should have converted to `template.JS` type before printing.

Ref:
http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS

This is new marshal function:

```
"marshal": func(v interface {}) template.JS {
  a, _ := json.Marshal(v)
  return template.JS(a)
},
```

Comment: A little more understandable: `encodedValue := json.Marshal(complexValue); replaceableValue := template.JS(encodedValue)`

Answer (score 0):

If your template has `<script>` elements, you can just pass a `map[string]interface{}` — or in general, anything that the `encoding/json` package would be able to marshal to JSON, like slices, structs, etc.

Go `html/template` templates render based on [contexts](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#hdr-Contexts):

> This package understands HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and URIs. It adds sanitizing functions to each simple action pipeline [...]
>
> At parse time each `{{.}}` is overwritten to add escaping functions as necessary.

Therefore it is not necessary with `html/template` to marshal to JSON beforehand. The engine will do it as appropriate.

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

const s = `<script>var arr={{.}}</script>`

func main() {
    t, _ := template.New("").Parse(s)
    t.Execute(os.Stdout, []string{"o1", "o2"}) 
    // string slice is marshalled by encoding/json package as JSON array

}
```

Prints:

```
<script>var arr=["o1","o2"]</script>
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/7TMbEwbKNYi