# Escaping values in JSON templates

Tags: json, templates, go, escaping, go-templates

Using `html/template` to create JSON output. Code snippet is as follows ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JtPhkwyGzuk)):

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
)

const tpl = `
{
    "key": "{{- .Value -}}" // Replace with js .Value to get another error
}
`

func main() {
    t, err := template.New("").Parse(tpl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err = t.Execute(&buf, struct{
        Value string
    }{"Test\\ > \\ Value"})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    data := make(map[string]string)
    err = json.Unmarshal(buf.Bytes(), &data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", data)
}
```

If I try to insert `.Value` as is - then I get the following error:

> panic: invalid character ' ' in string escape code

This is because `\\` becomes `\` and `\ + space` is incorrect escaping in JSON. I can fix this by adding `js` function to template:

```
const tpl = `
{
    "key": "{{- js .Value -}}"
}
`
```

In that case it fails with another error:

> panic: invalid character 'x' in string escape code

This is because `js` function converts `>` sign to `\x3c` and `\x` is incorrect escaping in JSON.

Any ideas how to get a universal function that correctly escapes strings for JSON? Is there an alternative way (e.g. an external library) to create JSON templates considering all these difficulties?

Comment: Probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482948/how-to-print-json-on-golang-template.

Comment: The template engine doesn't know about JSON syntax. You should use `encoding/json` to generate JSON output.

Comment: If you want to use templates, definitely use `text/template` not `html/template`, since the latter is (as the package name indicates) *specifically for HTML*. But really, `encoding/json` would be the more elegant solution for producing JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 0

https://play.golang.org/p/4DMTAfEapbM

As `@Adrian` suggested, using `text/template`, so we do need just one `unescape` and the end.

## Option 1

https://play.golang.org/p/oPC1E6s-EwB

Enscape before excute template, then unenscape twice when you want the string value.

## Option 2

https://play.golang.org/p/zD-cTO07GZq

Replace "`\\`" with "`\\\\`".

```
}{"Test\\ > \\ Value"})
to
}{"Test\\\\ > \\\\ Value"})
```

## one more

"// " comment is not supported in `json`.